# How to add new parameters to a java applet to call another method from javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, parameters, applet

I am using a java applet to call Web Services. This java applet is embedded in a html web page like this :

```
<object classid="java:TEST3.class"
                codebase="lib/"
                type="application/x-java-applet"
                width="5000" height="50"
                archive="sTest11.jar" name="TEST3" id="TEST3">
    <param name="TEST3" value="TEST3" />
    alt : <a href="TEST3.class">TEST3.class</a>
    <!-- Safari needs this -->
    <param name="JAVA_CODEBASE" value="lib" />
    <param name="BGCOLOR" value="000000" />
    <param name="TEXTCOLOR" value="FF0000" />
    <param name="TEXT" value="Test" />
    <param name="SPEED" value="250" />
    <param name="RANDOMCOLOR" value="1" />
    <param name="mayscript" value="yes"/>
    <param name="scriptable" value="true" />
</object>
```

So when the web page is opened, the applet starts. I have a javascript file which calls the init() method to call a first web service. Then I retrieve datas, that I need to call a second web service. That's why I need here to add parameters to my java applet. If I use in javascript :

```
document.getElementById('TEST3').innerHTML +='<param name="PARAM1" value="'+var1+'"/>';
```

and then

```
javascript:document.getElementById('TEST3').mymethod2();
```

it does not work. The applet is not reloaded. (but it works if I put manually a parameter before loading the whole page, so the problem is the reloading of the applet in order to take the new parameter).
I tried to call the stop() method, then the destroy() one, then another init() and then the request I want but it does not work.

I manage to do my requests with different applets (with several innerHTML which create each one applet step by step), but it does not work exactly as I want, and I really would prefer use only one.

If you have any idea, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try invoking your function like this instead:

```
document.TEST3.mymethod2();
```

And see if that works.

***EDIT***

Based off your comments I understand you were trying to pass additional *startup* parameters to the Applet on your page. Which is of course not really possible (keyword *startup* :). With your first method you had this:

```
document.getElementById('TEST3').innerHTML +='<param name="PARAM1" value="'+var1+'"/>';
```

But your object tag (correctly) doesnt have any *innerHTML*. And params are not specified in the object tag body anyway so no matter what this will have no useful effect. Your second method had this:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('TEST3').mymethod2();
```

Which according to your comments works, but of course there is no data getting passed in so your Applet parameters do not change. What you do want to do is this:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('TEST3').mymethod2(someparameter);
```

Of course, your method signature on the Applet should match!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have already tried this way, but it does not work. getElementById was the only way I found to invoke a method. But the way I do it works, I can call mathods which does not need new parameters... The problem is really to add parameters, to make them load by the applet.

Comment: It should work the way I listed it out. Are you saying you can't call for example ... TEST3.mymethod(someparameter), or are you trying to pass additional parameters to the applet itself (like the parameters you define in its body tag?

Comment: I try to pass additional parameters I define in the body tag, thanks to innerHTML - but it does not change anything because the applet is not reinitialized I think... But I thought I had to pass parameters only by this way (I am a very very beginner in java...)... I will try something like mymethod(parameter)...

Comment: @ishimakitu - ok, i see what you were trying to do. Yea, neither way you had in your question was going to work the way you wanted. See updates to my answer above.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is working fine ! Good to know that the way to pass parameter to a method in a applet with <param ... /> is not the only one.. and fortunately, it is like that !